# Email & report with task scheduler

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, automated-deployment

I am currently running my test scripts using a batch file & MS task scheduler. However, I would like to have an email sent out to our product team when the test has completed. Email would include a snapshot of the robot framework test report. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes,  it's possible. Find a command that sends an email on your system, and add that command to your batch file.

Answer (score 1):

The report is a set of HTML files which is not easy to open when distributed by email.

Consider setting up a CI server that can not only send out an email but keep the report on a web server. The email then contains a link to the right report.

I'm using Jenkins at the moment which has a plugin for Robot Framework. It keeps the full history of every test run and publishes graphs with the number of tests passing/failing.